# OpenAPI multimodule EAR deployment

Tags: open-liberty

I would like to package 2 openapi.yaml definition files with it's corresponding implementation, each one in it's own war file into one ear and deploy it to openliberty. So war this works and when openliberty start up it shows me the url for ~/openapi/ui and the corresponding REST-Services ~/converter1 and ~/converter2. When I use openapi/ui I only can see one Service definition, the second one I can not see. Do I something wrong? Should my scenario work with openliberty?

My general UseCase is to have severel REST-Services defined by OpenApi's grouped together as long as they are in a common domain. Until now I can run each openapi.yaml on its own OpenLiberty but I like to group my REST-Services together into one OpenLiberty Server.

Does somebody knows a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have noted, Open Liberty's MicroProfile OpenAPI support (via the `mpOpenAPI-1.0` feature) only supports a single application per server.

If you want to aggregate multiple OpenAPI documents in a single server you have to use WebSphere Liberty's `openapi-3.1` feature.  See these [docs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSD28V_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/twlp_api_openapi_agg.html) for more info.

Comment: As I understand now `openapi-3.1` is only able to be used with IBM Liberty Server, OpenLiberty does not provide this support, am I right?  Or is it possible to add this feature to OpenLiberty using another way?

Comment: That's right.  The best way to get this functionality into Open Liberty is to open a feature request at https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues and get a few votes behind that idea.